# Algebraic Three Systems of Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Given the three equations

\begin{align*}
a+b+c&=0, \\
a^2+b^2+c^2&=2,\\
a^3+b^3+c^3&=19, \\
\end{align*}

Compute $abc.$

I know that $(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2 = (a^4+b^4+c^4)+2(a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2),$ but this isn't leading me anywhere. Any ways to do this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take square and cube of the first equation. It'll probably help.

Comment: Hint: $x^3+y^3+z^3 - 3xyz = (x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz)$

Comment: Alright. The square of the first equation is $a^2 + 2 a b + 2 a c + b^2 + 2 b c + c^2=0.$ The cube of the first equation is $a^3 + 3 a^2 b + 3 a^2 c + 3 a b^2 + 6 a b c + 3 a c^2 + b^3 + 3 b^2 c + 3 b c^2 + c^3=0.$

Comment: @achillehui So I can say $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=0.$

Comment: Oh wait! So $19-3abc=0 \to 19=3abc.$ So $abc=\frac{19}{3}.$

Comment: In problems like this, don't forget the symmetry (for example, it's better to write $a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+ac+bc)$ than $a^2+2ab+2ac+b^2+2bc+c^2$). In this particular problem, the second equation is useless...

Comment: Is there a general proof for $x^3+y^3+z^3 - 3xyz = (x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(a^2+b^2+c^2) = (a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ca) \\ \implies ab + bc + ca = -1$$
$$(a^3+b^3+c^3) -3abc = (a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca) \\
\implies 19-3abc = 0  \text{ or } abc = \frac{19}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach:
$$0=(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+ac+bc)=2+2(ab+ac+bc)$$
$$2(ab+ac+bc)=-2$$
$$ab+ac+bc=-1$$
Similarly:
$$0=(a+b+c)^3=a^3+b^3+c^3+3(\mathbf{a^2b+ab^2+a^2c+ac^2+b^2c+bc^2})+6abc$$
$$0=19+3(\mathbf{a^2b+ab^2+a^2c+ac^2+b^2c+bc^2})+6abc$$
$$-19=3(\mathbf{a^2b+ab^2+a^2c+ac^2+b^2c+bc^2})+6abc \hspace{10mm} \mathbf{(1)}$$

Now you should consider how to evaluate the part in **bold** by making use of what you already know ($abc$ is already in equation $\mathbf{(1)}$). You should notice by playing around with the result $ab+ac+bc=-1$ that you get the terms in bold by multiplying
$$(ab+ac+bc)\cdot(a+b+c)=\mathbf{a^2b+ab^2+a^2c+ac^2+b^2c+bc^2}+3abc$$
$$-1\cdot0=\mathbf{a^2b+ab^2+a^2c+ac^2+b^2c+bc^2}+3abc$$
$$\mathbf{a^2b+ab^2+a^2c+ac^2+b^2c+bc^2}=-3abc$$

And when you plug it into $\mathbf{(1)}$ you get:
$$-19=3\cdot(-3abc)+6abc$$
$$-19=-3abc$$
$$abc=\frac{19}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

We don't need the condition $a^2+b^2+c^2=2$.

Indeed, $$19=a^3+b^3+c^3=a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc+3abc=$$
$$=(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}(a^2-ab)+3abc=3abc,$$ 
which gives $$abc=\frac{19}{3}.$$